# Average of three quizes out of six

Tags: moodle

On moodle I  have six quizes and I want to find the average of the highest three marks. How I can do that?

In excel it is easy using the "large" function that gives the nth largest value

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean highest grades? Grades in Moodle are a bit complex but here is a starting point for Moodle 4

Go to a quiz - click on the "results" tab which displays reports for the quiz

In the drop down next to "grades", select the "statistics" report

This will display the "Average grade of highest graded attempts"

The code to produce this is the `calculate` function in `mod/quiz/report/statistics/classes/calculator.php`

In that function there is a call to

```
list($fromqa, $whereqa, $qaparams) =
    quiz_statistics_attempts_sql($quizid, $groupstudentsjoins, $whichattempts);
```

in `mod/quiz/report/statistics/statisticslib.php`

There is code there to build the SQL, which you could copy and modify for your report.

Just to add, the quiz reports can also be downloaded as csv files - so you could manually download them, dump them into a spreadsheet and calculate from there